# If else Statment not working

Tags: c#, if-statement

Hi my If statement wont work for some reason I want it to say invalid if user goes below 0 or over 100 but every number i put in goes directly to my else statement doesn't even notice my if statement.

What am I doing wrong?

```
        g:
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Grade: ");
        int grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
        if (grade < 0 || grade > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input Valid");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input invalid");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        goto g;
```

Comment: Most grades are not less than 0 or greater than 100

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I saw that fixed it but now if i go below 0 it wont go to the else statement now :/

Comment: maybe you meannt `if (grade > 0 && grade <= 100)`

Comment: Should be `if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100)`

Comment: It is your logic, try to exchange the message. When the grade is less than zero or more than 100 you simple show a message of "Input Valid" instead of "Input Invalid"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some changes you might need to do:

```
int grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

and change your condition to `&&`:

```
if (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100)
```

Answer (score 7):

`if`/`else` is not a problem here. The way you're getting input from user is.

Use `Console.ReadLine()` instead of `Console.Read()`:

```
int grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

`Console.Read` returns numeric representation (ACII code) of the first character from console, not the number you've typed itself.

Comment: In addition, the if/else does seem to be inverted as @Johnny Mopp pointed out. It's a double whammy.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I did that I also notice my mistake with inverted X. But now when i input -1 it wont say invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Change your read statement as follows:

```
int grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

[Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the ASCII code that you typed, while [Console.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a string.